# Why does this jquery removeClass not work?

Tags: jquery

I have a function which adds a class, on page load, to the 2nd element of a list:

```
function top_view() {
    var elem = $('#sglsPosts .sglsPostContainer:nth-child(2)');
    if (elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.addClass('topView');
    }
}
top_view();
```

My inspect element shows that the class has been added:

```
<nav>
    <div id="moarUp"></div>
    <div class="sglsPostContainer cpHighlight1 topView"></div>
</nav>
```

Then, on click, I want to remove the class, so I tried this:

```
$('#moarUp').on('click', function () {
    var elem = $('#sglsPosts .sglsPostContainer:nth-child(2)');
    elem.removeClass('.topView');
});
```

I've `console.log` the output of `var elem` and it says:

```
0: div.sglsPostContainer.cpHighlight1.topView
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: n.fn.init[1]
selector: "#sglsPosts .sglsPostContainer:nth-child(2)"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

So that's right?

For some reason this does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo, Use `elem.removeClass('topView');` remove `.`

Comment: @Satpal That's not what's called a typo. That's a common error, though. And there was no need to add a comment when there was already 2 correct answers.

Comment: @dystroy, OP has use `.addClass('topView')` correctly so he knows that  one don't need to use `.` thus I feel its a typo. And yes it an error though. And sorry I didn't see your answer. I was lazy to not click new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside removing `.` from the name of the class you want to remove. You can also shorten your code using **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**:

```
$('#moarUp').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().removeClass('topView');
});
```

Comment: You get the tick for the added suggestion. Now I'm going to go sit in a corner and for not noticing the obvious. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a selector as argument but the name of the class. Change

```
elem.removeClass('.topView');
```

to

```
elem.removeClass('topView');
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why upvote ? Just don't downvote it when it's obvious. **I** wouldn't have upvoted it, at least as long as there's no need to show it's the right answer because of the presence of bad ones.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing.

Comment: @ dystroy: I have a fairly literal interpretation of "This answer is useful." :-)

Comment: @UzumakiDev This happens. No big deal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes but the problem is that we all end up with our very good answers having far less upvotes than the obvious ones. I'm sure it worries you too ;)

Comment: I'll mark this correct btw, just need to wait a couple minutes for stack to let me.

Comment: actually no offence but Felix provided the answer with a shortened selector.

Comment: @dystroy: Yeah, I've definitely had that happen. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the . selector on removeClass

Use just the class name instead and you should not have a problem.

```
elem.removeClass('topView');
```

Seee https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ for more details